# ESP32, подключение MIFARE-считывателей

Tags: esp32

Всех приветствую. Вопрос следующего рода. Имеется `ESP32`, есть необходимость организовать некоторое подобие СКУДа на её основе, соответственно, нужно подключить до 32, включительно, считывателей, выход у которых – `wiegand`.
Т.к. количества ног у esp никак не хватит, чтобы подключить все 32 считывателя, возникла идея повесить считыватели на, например [MCP23017](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/076/DOC013076230.pdf). 4 таких будет достаточно для того, чтобы обеспечить контактами 32 считывателя. Как читать это всё – определенные прикидки есть, заюзать возможность прерываний вышеназванных микросхем, по каждому прерыванию считывать состояние битов, складывать в буфер и потом парсить, формируя код, полученный по виганду от каждого из считывателей. Алгоритм, конечно, выглядит смутно, потому вопрос, насколько это вообще, на взгляд знающих, жизнеспособно? Как со стороны реализации ПО, оправданно ли такое извращение, так и со стороны физических подключений, будет ли вообще нормальным подобное решение?

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно никаких уплотнителей. Просто скрути линии данных паралельно в шину. Связь односторонняя и контроллером ты не разрулишь какой будет активен, какой нет.

Коллизии - прислонят карточку ещё раз. Ничего страшного. Ну или разбей считыватель на 4 группы если нужна высокая пропускная способность. Хотя если взять esp01 - они дешёвые до невозможности - их можно по одной к каждому считывателю припаять.

Лучше продумать обратную связь. На PCF8574 можно сделать крестики, стрелочки. Или на вашем mcp.

Comment: Сейчас в разработке схема, где есть пять ESP32, одна, условно, мозг, по CAN связана с 4 другими, которые обрабатывают считыватели, как раз группировка, схема в тестовых образцах рабочая, но схемотехник и техдир настаивают на рассмотрении варианта, где останется одна единственная ESP32, на которой висит всё. В параллельную шину не вариант, т.к. требование заказчика это запрещает. Вот потому и ломаю голову, стоит ли что-то придумывать, или продавливать то, что уже работает

Comment: протокол вигард шлет данные когда карточка прочитана сам и когда ему вздумается. я не вижу схемы как реализовать переключение "коммутатора".  возможно это реально сделать на программируемом контроллере вроде PIC.

Comment: или меняй считыватели на опрашиваемые.